# Error with Oracle trigger, invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I have the following DML statement that is working perfectly, i have tried to make it into a trigger but it isn't working.

**DML statement**

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0)* NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

**Trigger statement**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON HOLIDAY_RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
      NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = :NEW.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) * NVL(R.OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO,0) +
      NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = :NEW.ACC_ID), 0)
      INTO :NEW.SUBTOTAL
   FROM DUAL;
END;


Errors for TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
2/4      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/92     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "R"."OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO": invalid identifier
```

The error has to be in the * multiplying bit.

Comment: `HOLIDAY_RESERVATION`, which is aliased as `R` in your `UPDATE` statement , is not in the `FROM` clause in the `SELECT` query.

Comment: indeed i have set it to :OLD. thanks for noticing

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HOLIDAY_RESERVATION`, which is aliased as `R` in your `UPDATE` statement , is not in the `FROM` clause in the `SELECT` query.